# Notify iOS app to update its content

Tags: ios, networking, grand-central-dispatch

How can an iOS app be notified that it needs to update its content?

I would like to have an app that listens for update alerts that trigger a download rather than doing a data request to be able to stay in sync with the server.

What is the correct way to have an iOS app that needs to be in sync with a server stay in sync while minimizing network activity?

Im aware of using a cache locally, NSURL Cache or Core data etc. and adhere to the timeout in the http header etc. but I would like to correctly setup a sync mechanism without having an update button that a user needs to press to get updates.

I have thought of implementing a dispatch_source on a socket but wont that keep the network active and drain battery?

Rather than request a token for the version of the data to sync from the server I would rather like the server to notify the device that it needs to update. Is this practical?

How does the OS handle listening to push notifications? Is it on POSIX level?

Comment: You need to define what "needs to update" means.  How is the need recognized in the first place?  Who recognizes it?

Comment: Users could update data from their device to the server and then related users need to get the latest data seamlessly without having to fetch the data. I also want to minimize the network calls from both the server and device. So I would like the server to notify targeted devices about updates as well as trigger some updates as usual when loading certain views or whatever.

Comment: That's what push notifications are for.

Comment: They are clearly not reliable enough for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have two options here:

1. Client Side Polling: call the server and ask every so often. For 99% of apps this is fine as it's not that big a deal for someone to run the old version during the interval between polling.
2. Real-time Server Push: If for some reason you need to disable the old version as soon as you push a new version, you could do a server side push. You would *not* want to use APNS for this (user may deny APNS, delivery not guaranteed, etc). You would want to use a cheap push service like PubNub or Pusher for this to guarantee real-time delivery. Or code you own version using the same principles of these services, but really why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting PubNub and Pusher, I need real time updates.

Comment: AFNetworking 2.0 http://nshipster.com/afnetworking-2/ -  "Real-time - With this new release, AFNetworking seeks to set an agenda for real-time functionality. In the next 18 months, real-time is going to go from being a niche feature of the top 1% to how users expect things to work by default. AFNetworking 2.0 follows the Rocket technique, which leverages web standards like Server-Sent Events and JSON Patch to build semantic real-time on top of existing REST web services. "

Answer (score 1):

There are two common, as far as I am aware, approaches to doing this on iOS;

1. Regular GetUpdates calls to the server at an interval (Fairly standard across any platform I think)
2. Apple's Push Notification Server(APNS) if anything changes on the server you can push a notification to the device.

At work we typically implement both options because there are a few issues with APNS;

1. They are not guaranteed to reach the device, if the device is offline the APNS service will store the Notification for a limited time in the APNS system upon which it is forwarded (if it hasn't expired)
2. If multiple Notifications are sent while the device is offline only the most recent notification is sent
3. If the device is offline for a long enough period of time all stored notifications will be discarded
4. the user has to allow Push Notifications to be sent to their device because it suppliers and identifier that you can use to determine the device